# $form['redirect'] = "something=$someId"; doesn't work in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, redirection

I am here again with a problem! I want to make a form redirect usign a url with ids and somethings else as parameter, but when the code is executed something encode my url, so, if I put something like this **$form_state['redirect'] = "page=$nid";** I get this in the url "page**%3D**123456789" %3D is the =$. So, how i have to do that? I tested with utf8_encode too.

Can I use a drupal_goto() inside a form? Why yes? Why not?

Thanks people!

Comment: When do you want to redirect a page? do you want redirection when the form submission? If so, you can use drupal_goto() on submit callback.

Comment: @sathishkumar To redirect a form from its form submission handler, you should use `$form_state['redirect']`.

Answer (score 10):

What you set in `$form_state['redirect']` can be:

- a string containing the destination, such as node/1, admin/reports/status, or user/1.
- an array of arguments compatible with [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7).

The examples shown in [drupal_redirect_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7) are the following ones:

- This redirect the form to *node*:

  ```
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node';
  ```
- This redirect the form to *node/123?foo=bar#baz*:

  ```
  $form_state['redirect'] = array(
    'node/123',
    array(
      'query' => array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
      ),
      'fragment' => 'baz',
    ),
  );
  ```

In your case, if you want to redirect to `page/$nid`, you should use the following code:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = "page/$nid";
```

If you really want to redirect to `page=$nid`, then you should use the following code:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'page' => $nid,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if `destination` is set in the URL query string then setting `$form_state['redirect']` won't have any effect as Drupal will ignore it in favour of the `destination` arg.

Answer (score -1):

How to achieve,the below issue in drupal SAVE and NEW button.

If I want out of ten fields the top four fields of the same form to be pre filled again with the same data as I click on the submit button.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: This don't answer OP's question.

Comment: As the matter of fact its not a answer of the above statements It's a query which i asked ......as the trailing above things are somewhat related to the same am asking about......
So, Only i posted over here